# Error - "This version is not compatible with Drupal 7.x and should be replaced."

Tags: php, drupal-7

I am trying to create and enable a module in Drupal 7.59 and I am getting below issue on admin page.

`This version is not compatible with Drupal 7.x and should be replaced.`

The module name is "events" and the .info file content is

```
name = Events Creation
description = This module will create media events
core = 7.59
```

And events module code is

```
<?php
function events_menu() {
    $items = array();

    $items['test/events'] = array( //this creates a URL that will call this form at "examples/form-example"
        'title' => 'Event Creation Form', //page title
        'description' => 'A form to create an event.',
        'page callback' => 'drupal_get_form', //this is the function that will be called when the page is accessed.  for a form, use drupal_get_form
        'page arguments' => array('events_form'), //put the name of the form here
        'access callback' => TRUE
    );

    return $items;
}

function events_form($form, &$form_state) {

    $form['submit_button'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Click Here!'),
    );

    return $form;
}

function events_form_validate($form, &$form_state) {
}

function events_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
}
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please provide official name of the module - there are a couple Events modules, so a link to its official page and specifying the version you're using are key.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my mistake. It would be `core = 7.x`